# Copy one multiselect values to another multiselect

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-multiselect

I have one multiselect in cshtml page. When I click on button in cshtml page, I am showing Kendo Window. In kendo window, there is one more multi select and OK, Cancel buttons.

If user clicks on OK, I am calling controller and passing values of multiselect and doing the required operation.

I want to clear the values in cshtml multiselect and display the values of Kendowindow multiselect in cshtml page. How can I do this ? Here is my code.

```
$("#okay").kendoButton({
        click: function () {               
            var rowID = $("#selectedValues").val();
            data = { 'rows': rowID };               
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Rows" + window.location.search,
                data: data,
                traditional: true,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {                        
                    $("#Dialog").data("kendoWindow").close();
                    return true;
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("An Error Occured. Please Cancel and Try Again!");
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
success: function (result) {
    var selectedValues = $("#multiSelectOnWindow").data("kendoMultiSelect").value();
    $("#multiSelectOnPage").data("kendoMultiSelect").value(selectedValues);

    $("#Dialog").data("kendoWindow").close();
    return true;
}
```

My answer is based on an assumption that the two multiselect have the same data source. If not, you should think about update the data source of the multiselect on page.

See more on http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/multiselect#methods-value

Hope this helps!